# Number of orbits for abelian group actions

Tags: geometric-group-theory, projective-geometry, plane-geometry, abelian-groups, permutation-groups

Suppose $G$ is an abelian group acting faithfully on two sets, $X$ and $Y$, of the same size. None of $G$, $X$ and $Y$ is finite.

Now suppose $G$ is the union of abelian groups $G_i$, where $i$ varies over some (possibly uncountable) index set $I$, for which we know the following:

> for all $i \in I$, $G_i$ has as many orbits in $X$ as in $Y$.

Can we conclude that $G$ has the same property ?

If not, what would be natural properties for the family $\{ G_i \vert i \in I \}$ (or for $X$ and $Y$) in order that $G$ *has* the same number of orbits in $X$ and $Y$ ?

(For instance, what about if $X$ and $Y$ are the points and lines of an axiomatic projective plane, and $G$ is a group of automorphisms of the plane ?)

Comment: Is the number of orbits of $G_i$ in $X$ (or $Y$) finite for each $i$?

Comment: No, there are no restrictions whatsoever ...

Answer (score 4):

You could take $G=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, $X=G$ with the regular action, and $Y$ the disjoint union of two copies of $X$, and let $\{G_i\}$ be the family of cyclic subgroups of $G$.